# Indico text-sentiment php api not working properly

Tags: php, api, indico

I am just starting learning PHP and and I am trying to use Indico text-sentiment API but it is not working.

```
<?php
    require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
    use \IndicoIo\IndicoIo as IndicoIo;
    IndicoIo::$config['api_key'] = '9cdcfd0a.......';
    IndicoIo::sentiment("I love writing code!");
?>
```

It displays these errors:

```
> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null
 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\indico api\IndicoIo\IndicoIo.php on line 298  
>Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null
 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\indico api\IndicoIo\IndicoIo.php on line 300 
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception in C:\xampp\htdocs\indico
api\IndicoIo\IndicoIo.php:303 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\indico> api\IndicoIo\IndicoIo.php(64): IndicoIo\IndicoIo::_callService('I love
writing ...', 'sentiment', 'predict', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\indico api\text.php(7): IndicoIo\IndicoIo::sentiment('I love writing ...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\indico api\IndicoIo\IndicoIo.php on
line 303
```

Comment: You need to check the syntax of the code you are using. try reading the documentation that came with indigo.